# How to get WSUS server details from CyberArk Vault server?

Tags: cyber-ark, vault

When checked at path Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Update, I don't see any detail for WSUS.
Please tell what's the other way to check WSUS server details
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Qkxl.png)

Answer (score 0):

For WSUS server IP and port info, you can check below parameter's value:

1. Open regedit
2. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate`

   - "WUServer"
   - "WUStatusServer"

Answer (score 0):

You could find the information:

-At the path you mentioned:Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Update-> search for the parameter "specify the intranet microsoft update service location" and double click on it you should find the information you're looking for there

-Or use this command:
REG QUERY "HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate"